# Numpy find identical elements from list of arrays and another array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, identity

Suppose I have two lists `a` and `b`, `a` is 1D array with sub-arrays, b is 2D array without sub-arrays. How can I find the elements in `a` identical with `b` with keeping the structure of sub arrays in `a`?

```
   a = [array([[1,1,1],
               [2,2,2],
               [3,4,5]]),
        array([[0,0,0],
               [3,3,3],
               [5,5,5],
               [9,3,3],
               [8,2,2]]),
        ]

   b = array([[0,1,2],
              [3,4,5],
              [5,5,5],
              [9,3,3],
              [9,9,9]])
```

In this case, the identical elements are `[3,4,5],[5,5,5],[9,3,3]` I want the result to be like: (as well as extracting the index in `a`)

```
 >>> [array([[3,4,5]]),
      array([[5,5,5],
             [9,3,3]])
      ]
```

Is there any easy way to do it in numpy？

Comment: `a` is not an array. It is a list containing arrays

Comment: @MadPhysicist the code was ambiguous, I modified it into a list (it was just two arrays separated by a comma before, so a tuple)

Comment: Regardless whether `a` is a list or object dtype array, you get to iterate over its array elements.  So it comes down to matching rows of `a[i]` with rows of `b`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `a` is a list of arrays, you can use broadcasting to perform the comparisons of all elements:

```
out = [x[(x == b[:,None]).all(2).any(0)] for x in a]
```

Output:

```
[array([[3, 4, 5]]),
 array([[5, 5, 5],
        [9, 3, 3]])]
```

Indices:

```
[np.where((x == b[:,None]).all(2).any(0))[0]  for x in a]
```

Output:

```
[array([2]), array([2, 3])]
```

Comment: btw how can I also get the index in 'a' of the results? Can you please tell me?

Comment: `[np.where((x == b[:,None]).all(2).any(0))[0]  for x in a]`